How to build Visual Codium on NetBSD?
I am C++ developer and unfamiliar with script technologies like nodejs etc. I tried to build VS Codium on NetBSD 10.0 from sources 1.96.2 on github, by how-to manual.
After running build/build.sh it outputs:
...
+++ ../update_settings.sh
300s/'default': true/'default': false/
sed: -E: No such file or directory
219s/'default': TelemetryConfiguration.ON/'default': TelemetryConfiguration.OFF/
sed: -E: No such file or directory
114s/'default': true/'default': false/
sed: -E: No such file or directory
#

When I look into target directory vscode I am seeing there something like result:
vscode/cli/src/bin/code/main.rs
How to continue with build to reach binary executable "bin/codium" ?
What to do with that main.rs ? I read that it has something with rust ?
Can anyone put more light on this to understand what to do ?
I don't need to create installation package, it should be sufficient to run VSCodium from target build directory.
